# Google analytics apis v3 error 401 Login Required

Tags: google-maps-api-3, authentication, analytics, required

I'm working with google analytics apis v3 to receive traffic data, the language in use is php, the problem is that until a few days ago I obtained the data, now I have this error:
(401) Login Required
I logged on:
gmail.com
analytics.google.it
on the console of google is all enabled properly, because a few days ago it worked ..
here:
http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
working properly ..
The authentication code is this:

```
require_once '/analytics/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '/analytics/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('offline'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('#########ca1');
$client->setClientId('#########99.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('#########hs33t');
$client->setRedirectUri("#########/analytics/oauth2callback.php");
$client->setDeveloperKey('#########y86ePKOcHs'); // API key
# $service implements the client interface, has to be set before auth call
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
   unset($_SESSION['token']);
}
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
   $client->authenticate();
   $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

The parameter `$ _GET ['code']` is empty, and then the session token is not created.
Maybe it worked for a few days Just Because in the various tests of code That I did was logged.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the `$_GET['code']` as a parameter to the `$client->authenticate()` method, like that

`$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);`